# Use Microsoft Graph API to Obtain User Primary Email Address using Email Alias

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the Microsoft Graph API within a PowerShell script to automate the creation of Microsoft Teams teams. I am obtaining email addresses from a database of a proprietary non-Microsoft application that does not contain the Microsoft User Id. The Microsoft User ID is needed in order to add members to the Teams.

I am using the Microsoft Graph URI:

graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/

to obtain the User Id.

Unfortunately, that database sometimes contains an email alias rather than the user's primary email address. When the script attempts to obtain the person's User Id using an alias, the Graph API call returns an error.

For example, when the primary email is address is "jsmith@abc.com", but the database contains his alias "joe@abc.com" I was expecting to be able to call that API with a filter such as:

graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=alias eq 'joe@abc.com'

but I can find no such filter option.

I would appreciate any tips on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [user object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) has a property called `otherMails`. This is a multi-value property.

The [filter syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter) is different for multi-value-properties.

To filter users by alias, you'll need to use:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=otherMails/any(c:c eq 'joe@abc.com')`

Comment: I will give that a try and respond with my results. Thanks so much for the reply!

Comment: I tested this with a user that I know has an alias, but it is not finding it. This seems like we're on the right track, so I'll continue searching this filter construct.

Comment: You can take the ID of a user that has an alias and check in which fields you can find it. So `users/user-id-of-the-user?$select=*` and check in which field you see the alias. You’ll need the scope `User.Read.All` to get all the property fields.